# How to make two threads execute alternately？

Tags: c, pthreads

- I have two functions f1() and f2() I want f1() and f2() to execute
  alternately, without using a loop: Not like this : loop {
  f1();
  f2(); }

  I just want to use thread method My code is below:

  ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<pthread.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<semaphore.h>

   void *f1(void *vargp);
   void *f2(void *vargp);

   static sem_t mutex;

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       pthread_t tid1, tid2;

       sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

       pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, f1, NULL);

       pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, f2, NULL);

       sleep(100);

       return 0;
   }

   void *f1(void *vargp) {
       pthread_detach(pthread_self());

       while (1) {
           sem_wait(&mutex);
           printf("In f1\n");
           sleep(1);
           sem_post(&mutex);
       }

       return NULL;
   }

   void *f2(void *vargp) {
       pthread_detach(pthread_self());

       while(1) {
           sem_wait(&mutex);
           printf("In f2\n");
           sleep(1);
           sem_post(&mutex);
       }

       return NULL;
   }
  ```

The result always prints "In f1"    What should I do ?

Comment: Hint: condition variables

Comment: Your code prints both "In f1" and "In f2", what's exactly the expected behaviour and what's the difference with the one you get?

Comment: I still don't understand your mean, sorry, the mutex was set to 1, your means that was wrong? Could you give me more explicit answer？Thank u，I am a fresh man@Shawn

Comment: I want the result like:"In f1" "In f2" "In f1" ````@bccyv